# MySQL: Select based on values of another table

Tags: mysql, subquery

**Problem:**

In MySQL, I have the following table:

table1:

```
id           date               Count_0    Count_1      Count_2
1     2018-03-15 09:29:01         1          3            5  
2     2018-03-15 09:29:11         2          4            6
```

In this table, a new row is entered every 10 seconds with Count data (tables are actually several thousands of rows long) and have a fixed number of columns Count_x (say from 0 to 9).

I have another table which has the following structure:

table2:

```
id       name             
Count_0   a  
Count_1       
Count_2   c
```

This table has as many rows as the first table has Count_x columns.

Is it possible to have a query which will contain the data from the first output but only considering the columns which have a name in the second table plus de date ? In this example, the output would be:

```
       date              Count_0    Count_2      
2018-03-15 09:29:01        1          5  
2018-03-15 09:29:11        2          6
```

Bonus question: Is it possible to automatically change column names according to data in second table ? in this example the output would be:

```
       date                a          c      
2018-03-15 09:29:01        1          5  
2018-03-15 09:29:11        2          6
```

**My tests:**

I've tried using pivots which didn't work, or combined SELECT statements didn't really work:

```
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name <> ''
```

gives me correctly the Count_x with existing names

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='db' AND `TABLE_NAME`='table1';
```

gives me correctly the column names of table1.
Now I don't know how to combine those 2 queries. Am I going into the right direction ?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Id suggest you revise the design of your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @colname = null;
SET @query = null;
select group_concat(count_name) from table2 where name is not null into 
@colname;

SET @query = CONCAT('select date, ',@colname,' from table1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works correctly in a procedure. However, is it possible to have the same in a query ?

Comment: There is no possibility to do the same in a query. For example in normal select You have constant set of selected rows.